# Error when typing graph name in AgeViewer: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to create a graph using Apache AGE Viewer, but when I enter a name for the graph and click "Done", I receive the following error message:

subunit

```
An error occurred
Error Code: undefined
Error Details: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

I am running the latest version of Apache AGE Viewer on WSL2 with MacO  I am logged in as the Superuser and am able to create graph databases by writing queries manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new db cluster also check if you have node js 14.16.0 as it is prefered as this looks like a problem of a missing graph or an absent databse

```
bin/initdb demo
```

then start the server and create a database

```
bin/pg_ctl -D demo -l logfile start
bin/createdb demodb
```

just in case if you want to chnage the port number

```
bin/createdb --port=5430 demodb
```

load AGE

```
CREATE EXTENSION age;
LOAD 'age';
SET search_path = ag_catalog, "$user", public;
```

in another terminal start your age viewer

```
cd age-viewer

npm run setup
npm run start
```

another problem may be that you have not created the relation between the nodes
try this then

```
    SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$ CREATE (n:Person {name : "imran", bornIn : "Pakistan"}) $$) AS (a agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$ CREATE (n:Person {name : "ali", bornIn : "Pakistan"}) $$) AS (a agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$ CREATE (n:Person {name : "usama", bornIn : "Pakistan"}) $$) AS (a agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$ CREATE (n:Person {name : "akabr", bornIn : "Pakistan"}) $$) AS (a agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$ CREATE (n:Person {name : "james", bornIn : "US"}) $$) AS (a agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$ CREATE (n:Person {name : "david", bornIn : "US"}) $$) AS (a agtype);
```

Create nodes for country

```
    SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$ CREATE (n:Country{name : "Pakistan"}) $$) AS (a agtype);
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$ CREATE (n:Country{name : "US"}) $$) AS (a agtype);
```

Create the relation using

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$ MATCH (a:Person), (b:Country) WHERE a.bornIn = b.name CREATE (a)-[r:BORNIN]->(b) RETURN r $$) as (r agtype);
```

now visualize the graph

```
SELECT * from cypher('demo_graph', $$ MATCH (a:Person)-[r]-(b:Country) WHERE a.bornIn = b.name RETURN a, r, b $$) as (a agtype, r agtype, b agtype);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general troubleshooting that you can perform:

1. Update AGE viewer and ensure that the latest update is installed.
2. Check the logs to see for more detailed messages that will give you more info regarding the error you're facing.
3. Make sure that all the necessary environment variables are set correctly.